# Can the word "role" be used as a variant of "roll"?

Tags: word-choice

I read this sentence in a book named "Kafka on the shore":

> "Ms. Soga," he begins, "when they **called the role** in school your name would have come before Ms. Tanaka, and after Ms. Sekine.

Now, after a bit of Googling I came to this conclusion that the word "roll" is the correct version as per the dictionaries. But still I wanted a confirmation as after having been through almost half of the book, I've not found a single error like it. So I think this is the right place to ask.

Comment: It's a spelling error

Comment: Role and roll are confused quite often by native writers.

Comment: Actually, it's conceivable that the word is used correctly in that passage. But that's only by **assuming** that it's talking about an actual ***role*** that's being filled or applied to by several people. (For instance, it's the *candidates* for the ***role*** of proctor who are being called in alphabetical order.) It's highly unlikely that's the case here, but it's possible. I would be surprised if further context didn't rule out this interpretation. As already commented, it's almost certainly a typo.

Comment: Feel free to ask questions like these, in which you're asking for confirmation regarding a potential mistake in a sentence, in chat (either in ELL's or in ELU's) in the future.

Comment: What @userr2684291 said. But in addition I think these questions are valid ELL questions.

Comment: @EddieKal Somehow I think the community tends to close these based on this vague reason that because it's a typo/mistake, it's not useful, but given that native speakers (to be completely honest with you, it's *only* native speakers who do it) make this mistake, there might be value in preserving the question. At the same time, 31 views so far... it doesn't seem like people are looking this up (it's kinda obvious, after all).